# Is there a way to do this without a for-loop?

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, matrix

Currently I have this function in MATLAB

```
function [ y ] = pyramid( x )
%PYRAMID Returns a "pyramid"-shapped matrix.
y = zeros(x); % Creates an empty matrix of x by x.
rings = ceil(x/2); % Compute number of "rings".
for n = 1:rings
    % Take the first and last row of the ring and set values to n.
    y([n,x-n+1],n:x-n+1) = n*ones(2,x-2*(n-1));
    % Take the first and last column of the ring and set values to n.
    y(n:x-n+1,[n,x-n+1]) = n*ones(x-2*(n-1),2);
end
end
```

Which produces the following output:

```
piramide(4)
ans =
     1     1     1     1
     1     2     2     1
     1     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1

piramide(5)
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     2     2     1
     1     2     3     2     1
     1     2     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1     1

piramide(6)
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     2     2     2     1
     1     2     3     3     2     1
     1     2     3     3     2     1
     1     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Is there a way to achive the same result without using a for-loop ?

Comment: You can simplify the code by assigning a scalar `n`: `y([n,x-n+1],n:x-n+1) = n`. Is probably a little faster too. But why do you need to avoid loops?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the improvement. The task assigned to me doesn't allow the use of for loops.

Comment: This is a homework problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Durkee No. It's a challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use [`bwdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html):

```
function y = pyramid(x)
    m([1 x], 1:x) = 1;
    m(1:x, [1 x]) = 1;
    y = bwdist(m,'chessboard')+1;
end
```

Other solution using [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html):

```
pyramid = @(x) min(min((1:x),(1:x).'), min((x:-1:1),(x:-1:1).'));
```

Comment: Amazing! It would have never occurred to me.

Comment: like the one-liner :)